# Bootstrap with image icons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to bootstrap and was wondering if anyone could help me.

I want a menu with icons only, but trying to do it won't let me.

My HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Notifications</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"> Discover</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Messages</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I want to display icons instead of messages.

[image]

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: What do you mean icons instead of Messages? Can you provide an example of what you hope the nav items will look like?

Comment: where is your try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can include bootstrap `glyphicons` as icons using the below markup. Instead of text, update to `<i>` tag with respective glyphicon.

```
<div class="container">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
        <li class="active"><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open"></i></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<div class="container">
 <ul class="nav nav-pills">
  <li class="active"><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></i></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open"></i></a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```